# Nested SOAP Header Element

Tags: java, web-services

I want to create nested SOAPHeaderElement in Metro web services... It sould be something like 
I am using JAVA .JAX-WS 2.2.5 (Metro)

```
  <Auth>
  <UserName> data1
  </UserName>
  <Password> data2
  </Password>
  </Auth>
```

Metro provides WSBindingProvider to create headers but I want to create headers within `<Auth>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to implement a custom javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler and add it as part of a HandlerChain to the webservice provider.  some useful [getting started](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) info (more [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2007/jw-02-handler.html)).